# Firebase AuthProvider Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently building a Futter app with Firebase and I'm struggling because whenever a user logs in or out, the state auth notifier will get trigger and work as intended but it does not notify changes such as whenever a user verifies his email, changes his display name or changes his email. It does not even notify when a user converts his anonymous account to an email account.

The notifier code is:

```dart
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
Stream<User?> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();
```

and

```dart
final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authStateChanges` notifies about only the user's sign-in state such as sign-in or sign-out, not the ones you mention like changes to the `User` profile. Nevertheless, you can use [`userChanges()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html) method to listen on changes to any user updates:

> Notifies about changes to any user updates.
>
> This is a superset of both authStateChanges and idTokenChanges. It
> provides events on all user changes, such as when credentials are
> linked, unlinked and when updates to the user profile are made. The
> purpose of this Stream is for listening to realtime updates to the
> user state (signed-in, signed-out, different user & token refresh)
> without manually having to call reload and then rehydrating changes to
> your application.

However, it does not notify about email verification. As it stated in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state), events are fired **when the following occurs**:

- Right after the listener has been registered.
- When a user is signed in.
- When the current user is signed out.
- When there is a change in the current user's token.
- When the following methods provided by `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` are called:

  - `reload()`
  - `unlink()`
  - `updateEmail()`
  - `updatePassword()`
  - `updatePhoneNumber()`
  - `updateProfile()`

Also, `userChanges()` **will not fire** if you update the `User` profile via your own firebase admin sdk implementation.

You can force a reload using the following `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload()` to retrieve the latest `User` profile.